# Return row where any column matches input

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is it possible to create a SQL query returning a row which has any column matching input. For example:

```
SELECT row WHERE ANY column LIKE input
```

Thank you

Comment: `Like` without `wildcards` is equal to `= operator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ColumnA LIKE '%input%' OR ColumnB LIKE '%input%'
```

---

If you want literally to dynamically check *any* column then you need to dynamically build up the list of columns and use a [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

This will use the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html) table to find the columns in the table, then use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to put them into a string separated by the rest of the where clause. By itself this will give you:

```
ColumnA LIKE '%input%' OR ColumnB
```

Then you just need to [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) that with the start of the statement (`SELECT .. WHERE`) and the `LIKE` for the last column. All this gets stored in a variable `@sql` and used as the SQL for the prepared statement:

```
SET @sql:=(SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ', GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ' LIKE ''%test%'' OR '), ' LIKE ''%test%''') from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable');

# for debugging only
SELECT @sql;    

PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @sql;
EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement;
```

Here is a working SQL Fiddle to demonstrate this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f475d/22

Comment: Thank you very much for your correct answer and effort.

Comment: No worries - I just learnt an awful lot myself about MySQL I didn't know you could do...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for this...

```
  SELECT * from table  WHERE column a LIKE '%input%' or column b LIKE '%input%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `In operator`. since there is no `wildcards` in your `like operator` you can try something like this.

```
select row from table where input in (a,b)
```